# Changing GP parameter value type dynamically for ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcobjects, modelbuilder, geoprocessing, parameters

I'm building custom geoprocessing tool with ArcObjects where output value can be feature class or table with [GPFeatureSchema](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/gpfeatureschema.htm) as default schema. But the type of an output dataset depends on some option. In tool's [UpdateParameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/igpfunction2_updateparameters.htm) method I change schema of the output parameter to [GPTableSchema](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/GPTableSchema.htm) or to [GPFeatureSchema](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/gpfeatureschema.htm) according to this option. But in ModelBuilder any tool after the my one always thinks that my tool produces feature classes.

Is it possible to dynamically change type of schema with ArcObjects so chained tools get right output information from my tool?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(toolbox, tool_name).

Call the GPFeatureSchema tool.  This will open the dialog for the tool, and you can set the parameters.

You'll need to put it into a script tool, add the tool to your model where you want the dialog to pop up.  Then set the input into the dialog as a precondition for the dialog.

Here's the info for the pythonaddins:  http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//014p00000021000000

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I want to implement described logic without any additional tools and scripts. I hope there is a way I can do it with ArcObjects placing some magic code in UpdateParameters method of the tool. But it seems that it is impossible due to parameters list is recreated every time so all my manipulations with schema of the output parameter are lost...

Comment: Good luck doing this in ArcGIS as you described.  If you have access to FME, it would be a better tool for this task.

Comment: Also, if you know how you want to achieve a solution, list that in your question so people don't waste their time trying to help you

Comment: OK, although I have "arcobjects" tag on my question I added "ArcObjects" in the body of question. Hope it is clear now what I want :)

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, I am not familiar with ArcObjects.  If you end up finding a solution please post it as an answer if no one has answered by then.  You'll get a badge for that woohoo